# Error: Unable to resolve module `./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.d9da4ed7` from ``:

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I have a problem in react native, after installing the react-mqtt library and the dependencies (util, events, ...) I have an error when reading the Qr code with expo, i have installed dependencies by 'npm install'.

> Error: Unable to resolve module `./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.d9da4ed7` from ``:
>
> None of these files exist:   *
>   debugger-ui\debuggerWorker.d9da4ed7(.native|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json|.native.wasm|.wasm)
>   * debugger-ui\debuggerWorker.d9da4ed7\index(.native|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json|.native.wasm|.wasm)
>       at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\abaldelli\Desktop\ReactNativeTest\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
>       at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Users\abaldelli\Desktop\ReactNativeTest\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
>       at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\abaldelli\Desktop\ReactNativeTest\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:282:16)
>       at C:\Users\abaldelli\Desktop\ReactNativeTest\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42
>       at C:\Users\abaldelli\Desktop\ReactNativeTest\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1305:37
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\abaldelli\Desktop\ReactNativeTest\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:99:24)
>   tive.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json|.native.wasm|.wasm)
>       at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\abaldelli\Desktop\ReactNativeTest\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
>       at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Users\abaldelli\Desktop\ReactNativeTest\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
>       at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\abaldelli\Desktop\ReactNativeTest\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:282:16)
>       at C:\Users\abaldelli\Desktop\ReactNativeTest\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42
>       at C:\Users\abaldelli\Desktop\ReactNativeTest\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1305:37
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\abaldelli\Desktop\ReactNativeTest\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:99:24)
>       at _next (C:\Users\abaldelli\Desktop\ReactNativeTest\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:119:9)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

Here it's package.json :

```
    {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "buffer": "^5.5.0",
    "events": "^3.1.0",
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "npm": "^6.14.4",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-mqtt": "0.0.11",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "util": "^0.12.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Do you have the same problem and do you know how to solve it?

thank you for feedback.

Comment: did you solve this error?

Comment: @GouriShankar did you find a solution?